# How to translate ruby regex to javascript? - (?i-mx:..) and Rails 3.0.3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, regex

Im using validates_format_of method to check email format:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
```

also Im using livevalidation plugin to validate forms, so in my code Im getting:

```
(?i-mx:^([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})$)
```

Javascript cant read this regex. How or where I can change this regex to be as original:

```
/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
```

?

Comment: Relevant search results for this question [can be found here](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=(convert%7Ctranslate)+ruby+regex+to+javascript&oq=(convert%7Ctranslate)+ruby+regex+to+javascript&gs_l=serp.3...6611.13840.0.14133.12.12.0.0.0.0.123.1024.9j3.12.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.OIu4b055si4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=50b26647ad5972f8&biw=1366&bih=639).

Answer (score 9):

Ruby and JavaScript regular expressions are parsed and executed by different engines with different capabilities. Because of this, Ruby and JavaScript regular expressions have small, subtle differences which are slightly incompatible. If you are mindful that they don't directly translate, you can still represent simple Ruby regular expressions in JavaScript.

Here's [what client side validations does](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2011/11/18/convert-ruby-regexp-to-javascript-regex.html):

```
class Regexp
  def to_javascript
    Regexp.new(inspect.sub('\\A','^').sub('\\Z','$').sub('\\z','$').sub(/^\//,'').sub(/\/[a-z]*$/,'').gsub(/\(\?#.+\)/, '').gsub(/\(\?-\w+:/,'('), self.options).inspect
  end
end
```

The recent [addition of the routes inspector to rails](http://www.edgerails.info/2013/1/21/whats-new-55/) takes [a similar approach](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b67043393b5ed6079989513299fe303ec3bc133b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/inspector.rb#L42), perhaps even better as it avoids monkey patching:

```
def json_regexp(regexp)
  str = regexp.inspect.
        sub('\\A' , '^').
        sub('\\Z' , '$').
        sub('\\z' , '$').
        sub(/^\// , '').
        sub(/\/[a-z]*$/ , '').
        gsub(/\(\?#.+\)/ , '').
        gsub(/\(\?-\w+:/ , '(').
        gsub(/\s/ , '')
  Regexp.new(str).source
end
```

Then to insert these into your javascript code, use something like:

```
var regexp = #{/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i.to_javascript};
```

Comment: Converting `/.+@.+\..+/i` leads to double escapes the period, i.e. it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: `puts /.+@.+\..+/i.to_javascript` gives `/.+@.+\..+/i`

Comment: That said, the modern ruby regexp engine seems to leave regexps in a reasonably compatible state so for many regexps you may not need to translate. On Ruby 2.4.1, for instance: `puts /.+@.+\..+/i.inspect` also outputs `/.+@.+\..+/i`

Comment: A gsub approach can go some way, but almost every line of these solutions is incorrect. The top example will include incompatible flags, the bottom one will drop all flags. "\Z" isn't equivalent to "$". "\(\?#.+\)" will kill all following groups. Option groups can occur without "-" or ":". Whitespace *is* meaningful except in "x"-mode.

Comment: Thank you so much `to_javascript` is a magical method that works for me smoothly

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that you are converting your regular expression using .to_s instead of .inspect. What you need to do in your view is use .inspect to get the proper format. Here is some sample code that should explain the issue:

```
email = /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
email.to_s #"(?i-mx:^([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})$)"
email.inspect #"/^([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i"
```

so, in your javascript view do something like this to get the actual string representation you want:

```
<%= email.inspect %>
```

Comment: wow, works, `window.money.constants.EMAIL_REGEXP = #{raw Email::REGEXP.inspect};` then `RegExp(window.money.constants.EMAIL_REGEXP)` (using `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`)

Comment: actually `\A` and `\z` don't work, so `"dorian@dorianmarie.fr".match(RegExp(window.money.constants.EMAIL_REGEXP))` is `null`

Answer (score 3):

I've written a small gem that translates Ruby regexes to JavaScript:

https://github.com/janosch-x/js_regex

It can handle more cases than the gsub approach, and includes warnings if any incompatibilities remain.

Note that, whatever you do, not all Ruby regexes can be fully translated to JS, because Ruby's regex engine [has a lot of features that JavaScript's doesn't have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783721).