# Differences between Ruby 1.9 and Javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

Apart from Javascript's `^` and `$` being equivalent to Ruby's `\A` and `\z`, what other subtle differences are there between the two regular expression engines?

I'm looking for subtle differences where the same regex might behave differently, for example `/^abc$/` will match this in Ruby:

```
123
abc
def
```

But it won't match in Javascript.

Comment: There's also differences between particular versions of Ruby. Ruby 1.8 does not support look-behind assertions, while Ruby 1.9 does.

Comment: @tybro0103 Oops, should've specified which version.

Answer (score 18):

Features supported by Ruby, but not JavaScript:

- `\a` (bell)
- `\e` (escape)
- `\A` (start of string)
- `\Z` (end of string, before final line break)
- `\z` (end of string)
- Forward references `\1` through `\9`
- Backreferences to failed groups also fail
- `(?>regex)` (atomic group)
- `\G` (start of match attempt)
- `(?#comment)`
- Free-spacing syntax supported
- Character class is a single token
- `#` starts a comment
- `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class
- `(?i)` (case insensitive) (JavaScript supports `/i` only)
- `(?s)` (dot matches newlines) (?m)
- `(?m)` (`^` and `$` match at line breaks) (`/m` only in JavaScript)
- `(?x)` (free-spacing mode)
- `(?-ismxn)` (turn off mode modifiers)
- `(?ismxn:group)` (mode modifiers local to group)

Features supported by JavaScript, but not Ruby:

- `\cA` through `\cZ` (control character)
- `\ca` through `\cz` (control character)
- `\u0000` through `\uFFFF` (Unicode character)

Source:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Comment: Not sure how up-to-date that page is, but in ruby 1.9, `\uXXXX` sequences are supported by the regex engine.

Comment: As of Ruby v2.2, there are some more Ruby regex features which are not available in JS: (?(a)b|c) conditionals; \p{sc} unicode properties; ++ possessive quantifiers; [a[^b]] set nesting; [a-x&&c-z] set intersection; \h hex types; \k backreferences; \g subexpression calls; (?<=, (?<!, \K lookbehind; \u1F216, [-] astral plane chars and ranges.