# What does "?-mix:" mean in regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What does "?-mix:" mean in regex, also is this valid in javascript/jQuery? If it's not valid, what is an appropriate substitute.

**Update**: This is the full regex `/(?-mix:^[^,;]+$)/`

Its used in javascript in chrome, and I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?-mix:^[^,;]+$)/: Invalid group`

**Note**: I found this helpful: [How to translate ruby regex to javascript? - (?i-mx:..) and Rails 3.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854714/how-to-translate-ruby-regex-to-javascript-i-mx-and-rails-3-0-3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming perl context, `(?-mix)` this would

- -m disable multiline matching
- -i disable case insensitive matching
- -x disable extended regex whitespace

See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

> Not all regex flavors support this. JavaScript and Python apply all mode modifiers to the entire regular expression. They don't support the (?-ismx) syntax, since turning off an option is pointless when mode modifiers apply to the whole regular expressions. All options are off by default.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've now made it clear that the context here is javascript, I don't think javascript supports that flag syntax so it's complaining about `^` being found in the middle of a regex.  Since you can never find the start of a match in the middle of a match, this makes an invalid regex.

In javascript, you specify flags outside the regex itself such as:

```
var re = /^[^,;]+$/mi;
```

or as an argument like this:

```
var re = new RegExp("^[^,;]+$", "mi");
```

The `x` flag is not supported in javascript and this particular regex does not need the `i` flag.

What this particular regex is trying to do is to tell you whether the string you are matching it against contains all characters other than `,` and `;` and is not empty.