# Double escaping when converting regex from ruby to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I use this regex in Rails to check that an email address contains the basic parts:

```
/.+@.+\..+/i
```

I'm trying to translate that to javascript to do the same validation client side. I've tried a [method given here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854714/how-to-translate-ruby-regex-to-javascript-i-mx-and-rails-3-0-3):

```
var translated_regex = /.+@.+\\..+/i
```

and the gem [js_regex](https://github.com/janosch-x/js_regex):

```
var translated_regex = /.+@.+\\..+/
```

But `translated_regex.test('address@gmail.com')` don't work in neither of those cases.

What am I doing wrong or miss here?

Comment: No need to double escape the period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't double escape the dot:

```js
var translated_regex = /.+@.+\..+/
console.log(translated_regex.test('address@gmail.com'))
```

Comment: Thanks! Too bad the mentioned methods are erroneous.